# Python: How to list all methods in a module with what they can do and examples of usage?

Tags: python

I had expected that using a module name e.g `os`, and then using `-h` or `--help` will list all methods inside it. It does not work. I had thought that if I do the same with a method name then it will tell me what the method can do, its parameters and return types and examples but that also does not work.

How can I get list of methods and also information about what they can do and find more help for specific methods?

I am using an interpreter for Python and the above was attempted within it. I know I can get the information from google but it should be possible via command line inside the interpreter as well right?

Comment: You can use `help(os)` for example

Comment: You can read and docs online, or download an offline copy

Comment: It's not *necessarily* possible, but it happens to be.

Comment: `dir(module)` will give u all the mthods.

Comment: [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) is based on [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), so it's good practice to add docstrings to your code

Answer (score 0):

For default Python interpreter you can get all methods and variables of a module with `dir(module)`:

```
>>> import os
>>> dir(os)
```

`['CLD_CONTINUED', 'CLD_DUMPED', 'CLD_EXITED', 'CLD_TRAPPED', 'EX_CANTCREAT', 'EX_CONFIG', 'EX_DATAERR', 'EX_IOERR', 'EX_NOHOST', 'EX_NOINPUT', 'EX_NOPERM', 'EX_NOUSER', 'EX_OK', ...`

You can get help based on docstrings with `help(something)`:

`>>> help(os)`

```
Help on module os:

NAME
    os - OS routines for NT or Posix depending on what system we're on.

MODULE REFERENCE
    https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html

    The following documentation is automatically generated from the Python
    source files.  It may be incomplete, incorrect or include features that
    are considered implementation detail and may vary between Python
    implementations.  When in doubt, consult the module reference at the
    location listed above.
...
...
...
```

---

IPython has an additional macros that can show you the source code with docstrings:

`??something`

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> ??os
```

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py'>
File:        /usr/lib/python3.5/os.py
Source:     
r"""OS routines for NT or Posix depending on what system we're on.

This exports:
  - all functions from posix, nt or ce, e.g. unlink, stat, etc.
  - os.path is either posixpath or ntpath
  - os.name is either 'posix', 'nt' or 'ce'."""
...
...
...
if 'posix' in _names:
    name = 'posix'
    linesep = '\n'
    from posix import *
    try:
        from posix import _exit
        __all__.append('_exit')
...
...
...
```